# (How well) Did Juno provide any insight into the Flyby Anomaly?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, physics, flyby, scientific-data

I ran across an old BBC article titled [Juno: The spacecraft putting sling theory to the test — Why a probe passing our planet on its way to Jupiter might end a decades-old mystery, and reveal something completely new about gravity.](http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20131009-spacecraft-tests-sling-theory)

The Flyby anomaly is characterized as a very tiny difference between the measured change in velocity of a spacecraft after executing a flyby maneuver, and the calculated change, based on an exhaustively thorough modeling of all of the components to the gravitational field as well as all other non-gravitational forces have been modeled.

The question [Is the Flyby Anomaly still a thing?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23791/12102) shows a nice table, and I've included it here as well. For Juno, the entry only shows `~0` with an uncertainty listed as `not available`.

That there is a zero suggests that Juno did provide some information, but since the uncertainty is not available, it's hard to judge this significance.

What is the nature of this zero? Did Juno help as suggested by the BBC that it might, or were there problems leading to unanticipated uncertainties?

---

**Below:** From [The Flyby Anomaly: An Investigation into Potential Causes](http://issfd.org/2015/files/downloads/papers/153_Jouannic.pdf). Note the anomalous difference $\Delta$ is much larger than the estimated error $\sigma$ for flyby's *before about 2005*.

> [image]

Comment: About the "Note the anomalous difference $\Delta$ is much larger than the estimated error $\sigma$ for flyby's *before about 2005*." thing, I wonder if 2005 is when "they" noticed were starting to wonder if we are living in a simulation, so "they" added some more computing power to the universe? (humor)

Comment: Why do you think it's notable that "the anomalous difference Δ is much larger than the estimated error σ"?  That is $\sigma\Delta v$, i.e. the error on the anomaly, not the error estimated for the calculation of $v_\infty$, which would be $\sigma v_\infty$.

Comment: @asdfex I haven't looked at the paper in three years, so you'd have to use past tense in your comment (e.g. "why did you think three years ago that...") I'll give it a fresh read...

Comment: @asdfex you've omitted the rest and **operative part** of my sentence, which is "...for flyby's *before about 2005*." The key point that I'm noting is that anomalous behavior **goes away after 2005** and that's guaranteed by my criteria.  I haven't said that it is significant before 2005, just that it isn't after that. Please try to quote entire sentences and not just fragments thereof when combing for challenges. Thanks!

Comment: That's not the point. You're pointing something out as "notable" that is perfectly normal for any kind of measurement with a reasonable precision.

Comment: @asdfex you're asserting but not explaining sufficiently for me to understand what it is that bothers you so I have no further response. An answer post would allow space to flesh out exactly what is so wrong with saying "anomalous difference $\Delta$ is much larger than the estimated error $\sigma$ for flyby's *before about 2005*." and to construct a similar but correct sentence that has the same sentiment that the anomaly seemed to not be there after 2005. I think if I see the difference between the two it might be helpful. Your last comment doesn't really communicate useful/actionable info.

Comment: @asdfex instead, the last comment is simply saying "You're wrong!" louder. Just saying "You're saying X" where X is not close to what I said doesn't present me with any information that helps me understand.

Comment: @asdfex for example; Person A writes an equation on the board. Person B says "That's like saying 2+2=5!" Maybe Person C even giggles. Now Person A feels that they've been called stupid twice in one sentence; once for writing something that's supposedly incorrect and once for not seeing why what they wrote is supposedly like 2+2=5. And yet Person B has communicated nothing helpful or actionable, nor done anything to resolve the situation nor even to support their own assertion.